# How to extract data from JSON array using PHP?

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON :

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 1
                    [email] => 1@gmail.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 2
                    [email] => 2@gmail.com
                )
 )

)
```

This is my code (PHP):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$dulieu=$_GET['token'];
$url = "HTTPS://MYJSONURL.COM?url=$dulieu";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
echo print_r($json, true);
```

How to get result like:

```
1|1@gmail.com <br>
2|2@gmail.com
```

Comment: The sample 'JSON' you posted is not JSON... From the looks of it is just an array. Maybe rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$array = array(); //You can also use shorthand: $array = [];
foreach($json['data'] as $v){
    array[] = "{$v['uid']}|{$v['email']}";
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Glad to help, accept my answer if it help you :-) Thanks